# while reading metadata multi value field of a component, getting double the count of keywords in tom.net TBB

Tags: 2013, tom.net, metadata

I have a component with a metadata multiselect field as Location, for which options will load from a category. Users are allowed to select more then one option. I have below code which is working fine except giving the repeating value of options if selected more than one option.
 for example. If user has selected two locations i.e. location1 & location2 from the location field. 
  `IEnumerable<Keyword> fields = primarykeyfield.Values;` , **fields** is returing count as 4, and value its displaying as `location1,location2,location1,location2`.

```
private static string GetLocation(Component Comp, Engine engine)
    {
        string Location = string.Empty;

        ItemFields componentMetaFields = new ItemFields(Comp.Metadata, Comp.MetadataSchema);

        if (Comp.Metadata != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in Comp.Metadata.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name.ToLower() == "location")
                {
                    KeywordField primarykeyfield = componentMetaFields["location"] as KeywordField;

                    if (primarykeyfield != null)
                    {
                        //Get the Keyword
                        IEnumerable<Keyword> fields = primarykeyfield.Values;
                        foreach (Keyword kt in fields)
                        {
                            if (Location == string.Empty)
                                Location = kt.Title.ToString();
                            else
                                Location = Location + "," + kt.Title.ToString();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return Location;
    }
```

IT will be great if anyone can point the mistake so that i can get the result as location1,location2, on selecting two values from Location field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without running the code, I think the problem is your initial for loop.  If you look at the XML source of a Component with categories in the metadata (one of ours for example) :

```
<Metadata xmlns="uuid:f24b9067-dcb6-4ef1-8982-3dde4129fdab">
    <region>Singapore</region>
    <region>United Arab Emirates (Middle East)</region>
</Metadata>
```

If you then run `foreach` child node, you are effectively running your code twice.  Short version: you don't need the loop.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this mistake. After removing that loop problem got resolved.